# Trigger AFTER UPDATE for effected rows only

Tags: mysql, triggers

My Prestashop table ps_stock available has a column called quantity where the stock of the product is stored. This table is updated by an app, changing the values of the quantity column.

I need a trigger in that table. Every time the quantity of a product is changed I need to extract which products are effected on that table to insert them in another table

I have tried a trigger like this:

```
IF (OLD.quantity <> NEW.quantity)
THEN
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_ebay_product_modified (id_ebay_product_modified,id_ebay_profile,id_product)
SELECT ps_ebay_product.id_ebay_product,id_ebay_profile,id_product
FROM ps_ebay_product INNER JOIN ps_stock_available
WHERE OLD.quantity <> NEW.quantity;
END IF
```

What I need is a selection of the products that have been changed.

Comment: The trigger is fired once per "affected" row. So why would you want to know which other rows are "affected"?

Comment: Because I need to know all affected rows to update them in other table.

Perhaps firing the trigger just one time will give me all affected rows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER UPDATE ON ps_stock 
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      -- do some stuff here
   END;
```

Comment: Ok @MarEll in the section

"-- do some stuff here"

What code should I use to know the rows that have its quantity column modified?

That is the my need. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention the columns in your table ps_stock, i assume you have a product_id and the quantity. Given that you can just do something like `IF (OLD.quantity <> NEW.quantity)
THEN
INSERT INTO ps_ebay_product_modified (product_id, quantity_id) values (OLD.product_id, old.quantity); END IF; `

Comment: Thanks @MarEll. That does not works. Its complicated for me to explain what I need. Sorry for wasting your time. Will try using more info about tables and columns.